# Entity Framework getting Exceptions:System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type ''

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Entity Framework getting Exception:System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type ''. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
using (var ctx = ContextManager.GetContext())
{
    var executions = from e in ctx.Executions
                     join o in ctx.Outputs on e.ExecutionID equals o.ExecutionID into outputs
                     where e.Status == (int)ExecutionStatus.Pending &&
                                        outputs.All(o => o.Status != (int)OutputStatus.InProcess && o.Status != (int)OutputStatus.New)
                     select e;
}
```

All I want is the Executions that don't have new or inprogress outputs.
How can i write it differently so it will work?

Comment: Have you tried just not casting the enums, i could be wrong but I think EF will deal with turning them into ints for you.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. but unfortunately i tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: Create a view that does the join? EF might not be handling "outputs" well because it's not something in the model.

Comment: I prefer not to create a view so quickly. it should be a simple linq statement. all i want is the Executions that don't have new or inprogress outputs

Comment: What version of entity framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the enums outside the query and just reference the int variables. It is very likely the expression to SQL generator tries to interpret those casts as something to translate to SQL and not something to evaluate in memory.

Eg:

```
int p = (int)ExecutionStatus.Pending;
int i = (int)OutputStatus.InProcess;
int n = (int)OutputStatus.New;

using (var ctx = ContextManager.GetContext())
{
        var executions = from e in ctx.Executions
                         join o in ctx.Outputs on e.ExecutionID equals o.ExecutionID into outputs
                         where e.Status == p &&
                                            outputs.All(o => o.Status != i && o.Status != n)
                         select e;
}
```

Edit:
try to change your convoluted outputs.All( condition with a normal

```
where e.Status == p && o => o.Status != i && o.Status != n
```

Comment: @BenRobinson suggested that already. same exception... definitely this is not the issue.

Comment: @BenRobinson suggested to remove the casts altogether. I suggested to place them outside. That's a little bit different. Anyway if this does not work then your problem is not from the casts but from something else in the query. Without having access to your entity definitions I cannot give more ideas

Comment: anyway the other strange thing popping up is your outputs.All condition. Maybe i need some coffee but can you point an example of what would be the desired SQL for that?

Comment: i need something like this: 'var exes = ctx.Executions.GroupJoin(ctx.Outputs, execution => execution.ExecutionID, output => output.ExecutionID, (execution, outputs) => new
                        {
                            execution,
                            exists = outputs.Any(o => o.Status == (int)OutputStatus.InProcess || o.Status == (int)OutputStatus.New)
                        }).Where(item => !item.exists).Select(item => item.execution);'

Comment: even if it works you gained nothing if you don't figure out why the first one was wrong in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the help... the exception was from something else in the code. anyway the groupjoin was the thing i needed...

Comment: for future reference could you share what was the real reason? add it to the question text as a disclaimer. it might help other people in the future.